# Android: Can't save arraylist of hashmap which contains locations

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, save

I have a listview in which i have managed to save my current coordinates from the gps (Like a button which says add current location or something) in an

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I'm trying to save this list, so that it will be available after I start my application. I have tried all the different things like

```
@Override protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("savedLocations", list);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And then

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("savedLocations");
}
```

From the onCreate(),  but savedInstanceState is always null and after I hit the back button and the application closes, it never loads the list. Any ideas of how I could achieve this?

I know that the onSaveInstanceState will be called only after the application exits like clicking the home button and navigating to another application.

Comment: meta: use 4 spaces to format your code, so indentation and line breaks will get preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onSavedInstance state is only for storing state between when an activity is paused, and resumed. e.g. the device is rotated.
If the activity gets finished (when you back out of the app for example), the data is lossed.

To store data permanently, you could use shared preferences or a database.

Shared Preferences are really only designed for single values, usually a setting or preference the user has chosen.

You will want to use a database to persist your data. It can be a bit daunting using a database the first time.

I suggest a library called [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/). It abstracts a lot of stuff and has great api. It's very simple to use.

You need to persist your data in a database.

Comment: I will give a try to ActiveAndroid library and give you some feedback later

Comment: Unfortunately, i didnt manage to create a database and store my data. I tried many tutorials and none worked for me

Comment: Well that is really separate question, related to the libraries you tried, or sql databases in general. I would consider the above question anwered. If you are having problems with ActiveAndroid, post a new question and let me know. I'll see if I can help.

Comment: I solved my problem, i just created a sqli database from a tutorial that i foumd, and configured it to my needs. Thanks for minding :)